# Teamviewer controlling Ubuntu, need to confirm access?

Tags: windows-10, remote-access, teamviewer

So I have installed Teamviewer in Ubuntu and added it to the rc.local, and I've set up unattended access w/password. It's working and all that.

My problem is that I need to verify on my Ubuntu computer to allow to show the screen on my Win10 Teamviewer(so it can't be done via Win10 Teamviewer), and I need to request control access for the mouse to work, AND a third confirmation for me to be able to change settings on Teamviewer on Ubuntu.

Now, I'd like for all that to happen automatically.

If I do all this from my phone(Android), I don't need any confirmation.. So what's up with that?

Comment: *"I've set up unattended access w/password"* - IMO, that's a *really* bad idea. Just google teamviewer hacks.

Comment: Nah, I also have the thing on that will notify me by email and I need to give them access anyway. Several chinese people have already tried, and failed.

Answer (score 1):

Well it just so happened I was having the SAME EXACT issue. My solution (Done with Teamviewer 12 as of the time of this answer) relied mostly on the server (The one I wanted to control) and very little with the guest (The one that will have all the mighty power of the universe!).

It also changed radically on Teamviewer 12. The steps using Teamviewer 12 (And I will guess future versions) are the following assuming that:

- You have a teamviewer account. Does not matter if it's free or paid. You need a teamviewer account for this to work correctly.
- You have signed in with your teamviewer account on the **GUEST** PC.

On the **SERVER** (The one you will control) you will need to enable **Grant Easy Access** and **Setup Unattended Access**. So first on the **SERVER** click on Grant Easy Access:

[image]

And input your **GUEST** Email and Password for your Teamviewer account. You will get an email saying that you have been granted access to Teamviewer ID XXX-XXX-XXX

At this moment you can now join with the normal random password. The next step is the one that solves the other half of the problem. Click on **Connection** and then on **Setup Unattended Access..**

[image]

Input the name (Any name or nickname will do) of the PC you will be controlling (This helps when you are handling several PCs at once) and then add the fixed password you will be using to control the **SERVER** PC.

After this, using the **GUEST** PC, you can simply input the Teamviewer ID, then typing in the password and you are done.

To Enable Teamviewer at Startup, on Both, Windows and Linux you can go to:

**Extras -> Options -> General**

and you will enable the option:

- Start TeamViewer with Windows (Windows version of TeamViewer)
- Start TeamViewer with System (Linux version of TeamViewer)

Comment: Didn't work here. I'm logged in on both the guest and the server(so I don't need the ID things every time). 

After pressing the grant easy access on the server, running the unattended access wizard again then closing the connection, reconnect. It's still asking for access to view the screen and controlling the mouse as well as doing anything with Teamviewer. Do I have to restart the computer or Teamviewer for this to work?

Comment: @stefanw1337 What I did on my case was (On Windows 10), do the steps mentioned here (I even tested yesterday again), and then on the Ubuntu computer, I simply added the ID and when trying to log in, I put the password. Just in case you do have to use a password. This is mandatory to be able to login to any teamviewer computer. If you would like, I can provide a google hangout session, simply email me and I will lend a hand on this.

Comment: I need to try some more first, like restart and stuff. Also noticed that the clipboard don't work either. And yes, it's toggled on in Options->Advanced->Clipboard sync. This new Teamviewer version right out sucks.

Comment: @stefanw1337 Yeah it does. Has several bugs also on my end.